# Check if Java App is running from C# .NET

Tags: c#, java, .net

I launch a game server application from a .bat file currently using this...

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

I would like to be able to check if it is running or not from a C# .NET application. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: I forgot to mention I have multiple running at one time so checking for the process name won't work.

Comment: Question unclear: do you need Java program to check if a .NET program called the batch file?

Comment: I think the gist of his question was to check if a java process, which was launched by a batch file, is running, checking from a C# application.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class, you can find the java processes but you won't be able to tell what they are executing.  You'd need to be able to inspect their command line at least to determine this.  If all your Minecraft servers are started with the same command line arguments, you could use WMI to find.  You could get the associated associated Process objects if you want to do what you need.

```
// find all java processes running Minecraft servers
var query =
    "SELECT ProcessId "
    + "FROM Win32_Process "
    + "WHERE Name = 'java.exe' "
    + "AND CommandLine LIKE '%minecraft_server%'";

// get associated processes
List<Process> servers = null;
using (var results = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query).Get())
    servers = results.Cast<ManagementObject>()
                     .Select(mo => Process.GetProcessById((int)(uint)mo["ProcessId"]))
                     .ToList();
```

You'll need to add a reference to the `System.Management.dll` library and use the [`System.Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace.

The existence of such processes is enough to know it is running.  You could also determine if and when it ends by inspecting each process' properties such as [`HasExited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx) or wait for it using [`WaitForExit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a .bat file to launch java, you might consider looking into the [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) from .Net. It has all sorts of goodies for dealing with processes.

If you want to be checking on the game server constantly over a stretch of time, you probably will have to use it with some sort of [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) or [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), but the Process class ought to lead you in the right direction.

Hope this helps.